# shift all array elements up one level in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array that may look like

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'test1' => 'testing1'
    ),
    array(
        'test2' => array(
         1 =>'testing2
    )
);
```

and I want to turn it into

```
$newArr = array(
    'test1' => 'testing1',
    'test2' => array(
         1 => 'testing2'
     )
);
```

so i have been trying to shift all array elements up one level.

eidt:

this is my method that combines 2 array together:

```
public function arrayMerge($arr1, $arr2)
            {
                foreach($arr2 as $key => $value) {

                    $condition = (array_key_exists($key, $arr1) && is_array($value));
                    $arr1[$key] = ($condition ? $this->arrayMerge($arr1[$key], $arr2[$key]) : $value);
                }

                return $arr1;
            }
```

Comment: I needed to do the same thing, although I found that simply doing `$newArray = $oldArray[0]` was all it took to solve the problem.  Would this not work in your case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
$arr = array(
        array('test1' => 'testing1' ), 
        array('test2' => array(1 =>'testing2')) 
);

$new = array();
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $new += $value;
}
var_dump($new);
```

Output

```
array
  'test1' => string 'testing1' (length=8)
  'test2' => 
    array
      1 => string 'testing2' (length=8)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked perfect in combination with my arrayMerge() method!

Comment: Is there no **built-in function** to do this **WITHOUT** using a `foreach`? It would be easier **to convert multidimensional array into single dimensional in PHP**

Comment: I was searching for such a built-in function for a long time because we cannot use nested 3 to 4 foreach loops to extract data from array. If someone could come up without using foreach esp: with built in function then I would call him/her as a crown of PHP.

Answer (score 28):

It's somewhat trivial, many ways are possible.

For example using the [array union operator (`+`)<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.array.php) creating the union of all arrays inside the array:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $subarray)
    $newArr += $subarray;
```

Or by using [`array_merge`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_merge) with all subarrays at once via [`call_user_func_array`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$newArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
```

Comment: I prefer this method because avoid the "foreach" loop. Thanks.

Comment: Starting from PHP 5.6 you can use splat operator ```$arr = array_merge(...$arr)```. It's significantly faster than call_user_func_array